# Match a literal dot and a new line in a text (regex)

Tags: python, regex, newline

I have the following text `"DTMS - Specifiche\nL'utilizzo dei negativi su vetro si diffonde a partire dal 1850 circa ed \ninizia intorno al 1920.\nPagina \n3\n di \n4\nAU "`.

I'd like to take all the text from `L'utilizzo` to `.\n`. I have tried with `DTMS - Specifiche\n(.+?)\n` but it ends when the code finds the first `\n`. I also tried with `DTMS - Specifiche\n(.+?)[.]\n` because I think that I need to escape the dot, but it doesn't work as I would.

Is there anyone who can figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match till the first dot and a newline:

```
DTMS - Specifiche\n([\S\s]*?\.)\n
```

If you don't want the dot, you can move it outside of the capture group.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZMYtWb/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"DTMS - Specifiche\n([\S\s]*?)\.\n"

s = ("DTMS - Specifiche\n"
            "L'utilizzo dei negativi su vetro si diffonde a partire dal 1850 circa ed \n"
            "inizia intorno al 1920.\n"
            "Pagina \n"
            "3\n"
            " di \n"
            "4\n"
            "AU ")

m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
L'utilizzo dei negativi su vetro si diffonde a partire dal 1850 circa ed 
inizia intorno al 1920.
```